# Disable Variable Product Price Range on the WooCommerce Single Product Pages Only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm looking to hide variable products price range only on the single product pages for the product that is currently being viewed. I do not want the price range to be disabled for all the products listed in the "Related Products" below and any products listed in the widgets in the footer as well.

Everyone of the snippets I've found so far hides the price range for every product listed on the single products page. It also hides the price completely from view from the variable products that have the exact same price for all of them since they do not display below the drop down when selected.

Here is an example of a snippet I've found:

```
/*
Disable Variable Product Price Range completely:
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'my_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'my_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );

function my_remove_variation_price( $price ) {
  $price = '';
  return $price;
}
```

Example of price issue below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look on [the Visual Hook Guide](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/). The price range is a part of the single product summary. The `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook consists of:

```
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
```

And the `woocommerce_template_single_price` function adds the `single-product/price.php` template-part.

So we have two ways:

### 1. Remove this template part for variable products only

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_remove_variation_price' );
function my_remove_variation_price() {
  global $product;
  if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
  }
}
```

### 2. Or edit the template part itself

Copy `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php` to `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/woocommerce/single-product/price.php` and replace this code fragment

```
  <p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
```

with this one

```
<?php if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) : ?>
  <p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'ninja_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'ninja_remove_variation_price', 10, 2 );

function ninja_remove_variation_price( $price ) {
if ( is_product() ) {
$price = '';
}
return $price;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's still returning all variable products without prices that are mentioned in the Related Products below the single product and footer widgets.

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove "From" text without removing the price completely for variable products.

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html','variation_price_min', 9999, 2 );

  function variation_price_min( $price, $product ) {
  $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
  $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );
  $price = sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_price ) );
  return $price;
   }
```