# Hide product variation price range in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

When I add variable products to my shop I got a price range on the catalogue and product page. I found a way to show only minimum price instead of the price range. It works great. (see code below).

But now I would like to hide those minimum price on the product pages (but only on product pages!). Because there is already a price showing when picking a product from the variable list. So it will be a bit confusing and bad looking if there is 2 price displaying. (see picture below).

My code actually:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2); 

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) { 

 $price = '';

 $price .= wc_price($product->get_price()); 

 return $price;
}
```

Any idea how this can be done ?

There is two price in variable product single pages:

[image: there is two price in product pages !]

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why the answer of LoicTheAztec dont work with me. But I found a solution. In

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php
```

I have replaced :

```
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
```

with this one :

```
<?php if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) : ?>
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This together with the code inside my question, it is now showing minimum price of variable products everywhere but no price at all in the product page of variable products.

Answer (score 0):

Since the price range is part of the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook, we can achieve this by removing the `woocommerce_template_single_price` callback function from the action hook `woocommerce_single_product_summary`.

**This code will remove the price range below product title for variable products only, on single product pages.**

```
/** Remove price variation below title for variable products on single product page **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_remove_variation_price' );
function my_remove_variation_price() {
  global $product;
  if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
  }
}
```

Answer was found on this thread, with a very good explanation:
[Disable Variable Product Price Range on the WooCommerce Single Product Pages Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447112/disable-variable-product-price-range-on-the-woocommerce-single-product-pages-onl)

**This code will remove the price below product title for single products only, on single product pages.**

```
/** Remove price below title for single products on single product page **/
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_remove_variation_price' );
    function my_remove_variation_price() {
      global $product;
      if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
      }
    }
```

**This code will remove the price below product title indifferent from product type, on single product pages.**

```
/** Remove price below title for all product types on single product page **/
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_remove_variation_price' );
        function my_remove_variation_price() {
          global $product;
          if ( $product ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
          }
        }
```

The code to be added in your `function.php` file of your active `child-theme`. It is not necessary to use all the codes. Use only one, and change the `if` statement to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to modify variable product on loop and single product to display the highest price:

```
/* Modify variable product to display the highest price*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_min_max_variable_price_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_min_max_variable_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
    $count  = (int) count( array_unique( $prices['price'] ));

    // When all variations prices are the same
    if( $count === 1 )
        return $price;

    $max_price = max( $prices['price'] );
    $max_keys = array_search( $max_price, $prices['price'] );

    $max_reg_price = $prices['regular_price'][$max_keys];
    $max_price_html = wc_price( $max_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix();

    // When max price is on sale (Can be removed)
    if( $max_reg_price != $max_price ) {
        $max_price_html = '<ins>' . $max_price_html . '</ins>';
        $max_price_reg_html = '<del>' . wc_price( $max_reg_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del>';
        $max_price_html = $max_price_reg_html . ' ' . $max_price_html;
    }
    $price = sprintf( __( ' %s', 'woocommerce' ), $max_price_html );

    return $price;
}
```

I check it and work on my site. You can put it at the **function.php** file on your child-theme.